# How to find the full path of a file from my Desktop in Centos?

Tags: centos, software-installation

My folders in desktop:

[image: my folder in desktop]

My folder name about which I'm interested is `Ram`:

[image: what are the sub folders in my main folders]

[image]

I tried the following command for installing `yoono-desktop`:

```
[root@localhost mpatil]# tar jxf ~/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2 tar
tar (child): /root/Ram/Downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have root and password. I tried as root.